# How do you highlight the field in rdlc report if changed from previous row?

Tags: c#, rdlc, audit

I'm creating a report based on an audit table, and I want to highlight the field that has changed since the previous revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Previous Function, in the field properties, select font and set a formula for bold style should be something like

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!myField.Value) = Fields!myField.Value, Default, Bold)
```

This should solve your problem you can find the documentation here [Previous Function (Visual Studio Report Designer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms251678(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I wound up using something similar to what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using something similar to what you suggested.

In the BackgroundColor property of the textbox, I used the following code.

```
=IIf(Fields!Revision.Value=1,"Transparent",IIf(Fields!ReasonID.Value=Previous(Fields!ReasonID.Value),"Transparent","LightGrey"))
```

Basically if revision = 1, it is the first revision so it is transparent (no highlighting), that is the true portion of the first iff.

In the else section of the first iff I checked if the value of the field was the same as that of the previous value of the field, if true, I set the background to transparent (no highlighting), in the else section I set the background to light grey.

This had the desired effect of highlighting in grey all field that had changed from the previous row.

Thanks